# Insert numeric variable into SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I insert a numeric variable in a statement from within a stored procedure (here is my attempt):

```
...
declare @SQL1 nvarchar(1500)
declare @calc numeric(18,2)
Set @calc = 18.00
SET @SQL1= 'insert into Table1(cv) values(' + @calc + ')'
```

The error I get on the last line is:

> *Error converting data type varchar to numeric.*

If I insert a variable of type `nvarchar` like this:

```
SET @SQL1= 'insert into Table1(cn) values(''' + @column_name + ''')'
```

it works like a charm - but not when I try to insert a numeric field as above in the first example.
Thank you!

PS: The table Table1 was correctly defined for its columns to match the variable types. Table1 has 2 columns: `cn` of type `nvarchar(50)` and `cv` of type `numeric(18,2)`. `@column_name` is `nvarchar(50)` and `@calc` is `numeric(18,2)`.

Comment: One query has `cn` as a field, the other `cv`. Which is right, and what are their data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **cast** your numeric to a `nvarchar` - try this:

```
declare @SQL1 nvarchar(1500)
declare @calc numeric(18,2)

Set @calc = 18.00

SET @SQL1 = N'insert into Table1(cv) values(' + CAST(@calc AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N')'
```

Comment: Great, worked like a charm, thank you. I had the funny feeling Sql was automatically converting to nvarchar and the statement was expecting a number to match the 'cv' column type. I'm not sure why this happens but glad to apply your solution.